# Update rows in a table from form textfields populated by a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below PHP/HTML that populates form fields using a while loop from the `global_settings` table

```
<?php
$global_sql2="SELECT name, field, value FROM global_settings";
$global_rs2=mysql_query($global_sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($global_result2=mysql_fetch_assoc($global_rs2))
{
    echo '<tr>
                <td><strong>'.$global_result2["name"].'</strong></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="'.$global_result2["value"].'" size="50" value="'.$global_result2["value"].'" /></td>
            </tr>';
}
?>
```

When the form is submitted, each row in the database needs to be updated with the values typed in the text fields.

for example, in the database there is a row with the following:

```
name = Company Name
field = company_name
value = Company ABC
```

the the posted value is set as Company XYZ

so the SQL should say:

```
`UPDATE tablename set value = 'Company XYZ' where field = 'company_name'`
```

but its not, is saying:

```
UPDATE tablename set value = 'Company XYZ' where field = 'company_name'

    <?php
$global_sql3="SELECT name, field, value FROM global_settings";
$global_rs3=mysql_query($global_sql3,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($global_result3=mysql_fetch_assoc($global_rs3))
{
    $sql="UPDATE global_settings set value = '".$_POST[$global_result3["field"]]."' where field = '".$_POST[$global_result3["value"]]."' ";
    echo '<br><br>'.$sql;
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<h3>Successfully Updated</h3>';
}
?>
```

the table is called `global_settings` and there are columns `(name, field, value)`

so basically, name and field fields NEVER get changed by the user just the value field

the `value` field in `global_settings` is not updating when the values in the text fields are changed - im not sure what the issue is

Comment: And here we go again. @charlie: Please keep this question and reedit it if there are new aspects to it. But please don't delete and repost it again and again.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in all of this?

Comment: You cannot specify the column to be updated in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said yesterday on another post of this question:

You have to change this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="'.$global_result2["value"].'" size="50" value="'.$global_result2["value"].'" /></td>
```

into this

```
<td><input type="text" name="'.$global_result2["field"].'" size="50" value="'.$global_result2["value"].'" /></td>
```

Or else you can't access it via `$_POST[$global_result3["field"]]`.

You also have to change this line:

```
$sql="UPDATE global_settings set value = '".$_POST[$global_result3["field"]]."' where field = '".$_POST[$global_result3["value"]]."' ";
```

into this:

```
$sql="UPDATE global_settings set value = '".$_POST[$global_result3["field"]]."' where field = '".$global_result3["field"]."' ";
```

And like i said in your previous postings:

Switch to mysqli_* functions. ext/mysql is deprecated. And always escape your values before inserting them into a sql-query!

Answer (score 0):

there is a little problem in you code

change

`<td><input type="text" name="'.$global_result2["value"].'" size="50"`

by

```
`<td><input type="text" name="'.$global_result2["field"].'" size="50" `
```

Comment: but it"s about the field not the value $global_result2["value"]

Comment: i get this SQL when i change the name of the text field like that: UPDATE global_settings set value = 'eee' where field = 'eee'

Comment: no, you have to change it in the while wsich print the html form

Comment: did you changed the lines ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input type="text" name="'.$global_result2["value"].'" ...
                                                  ^
                                                  |
                                                  +-- problem is here
```

Change it to

```
<td><input type="text" name="'.$global_result2["name"].'" ...
```

**Update**

Given you have a table like so:

```
+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|     name         |       field       |      value      |
+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|    Company Name  |    company_name   |      XYZ        |
+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

You can get your form show the info like this

```
while(...) {
  echo '<tr><td><strong>' . $row['name'] . '</strong><input name="' . $row['field'] . '" value="' . $row['value'] . '"/></td></tr>';
}
```

Then, you should compose your UPDATE queries like so:

```
foreach($_POST as $f => $v) {
  $query = "UPDATE `table` SET `value` = '$v' WHERE `field` = '$f'";
}
```

Comment: i get this SQL: UPDATE global_settings set value = '' where field = ''

Comment: @charlie then you don't have a value for the `name` field, which means your data is corrupt.

Answer (score -1):

You are only updating the value column,

```
UPDATE tablename set value = 'Company XYZ' where field = 'company_name'
```

To update other columns, you have to add the columns which you want to update in the SET statement.

```
UPDATE tablename set value = 'Company XYZ', name = 'name', field = 'field' where field = 'company_name'
```

Comment: This won't help you at all ... Because you said that only the value column is changing. So why update the other two?

Comment: @TobiasKun : I understand your comment, but even if it's a strange request, i answer on what he wants. I was also scratching my hair for a second when reading his question. It's "so basically, name and field fields NEVER get changed by the user just the value field". Deciphering time.

Comment: @KarelG: I only was confused why he would say that this is what he wanted, because his "question" did not said anything about this.
Though there were other errors in his script that prevented it from fulfilling his desired result.